# Methods for quantifying a network of coupled oscillators

Tags: statistical-mechanics, oscillators

I usually am more on the statistics part of things, so pardon my misuse of the terminology. I am simulating a network of non-pulse coupled non-linear oscillators ( I am not sure what the correct term for that is). The network topology is one of the parameters I'm investigating, but considering nearest d-neighbours and scale free networks.

I am interested in finding a method for analyzing (or summarizing, like a statistic) the phase relations of the whole network, given time varying forcings applied to each oscillator.
Preferentially, I'm looking for a model free approach, so that I don't have to simplify the dynamics of the oscillators.

Comment: It is not very clear what you're after. +1, but the more detail you provide, the more it is likely that someone can help you.

Comment: Ok @Emilio Pisanty, what aspect should I clarify? I have a network of non-linear oscillators, with various potential topologies. I want to find a minimal-assumption approach to quantify the phase relations within a network.

Comment: For one, it would be helpful to clarify the nature of the nonlinearity. Mostly, though, I don't really understand what you mean by "quantify the phase relations" between oscillators. What sort of forcings are you using? Are they related to each other in phase or frequency?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, the oscillators represent neural units, all which oscillate, albeit at different frequencies and amplitudes. The communication is done by exchanging currents (via Ohmic resistances). If I understand correctly this makes the cells related in phase. The forcings represent time-varying stochastis process, which again affect the cellular dynamics by injecting current. I hypothesize that the units will cluster into ensembles with similar frequency and amplitude, locked in relative phases. I want to see what happens when you dynamically change the resistances between the cells.

Comment: Are the stochastic process driving each oscillator independent, or are they related in any way?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Their correlation is one of the free parameters, but initially we assume a Gaussian random field.

Comment: To be honest with you, I'm not really in a position to answer your question. However, it is clear to me that any attempt at characterizing the relationships between the different oscillators' motion is hopeless without a clear description of the relationships between the forces that act on them. (Two trivial examples are identical oscillators driven by phase-locked forcings, which will always be in phase, and weakly-bound oscillators driven by strong, completely uncorrelated forcings, which will have no definite phase relation. Your case is somewhere in the middle, but where is that?)

Comment: Thus you should see my questions as advice on information which you should edit into your post, to give it the best chance of finding an answer. So, therefore: how are you parametrizing the correlation between the oscillators?